# MetroLog in Maui app - be able to provide custom log name

Tags: maui, metrolog

**MetroLog** generates the log name of its own in my android app, something like **'Log - 20221211'**. But I want to **rename to** something else that would contain the user name who is logged in, something like **'Log - 20221211-tim'** for 'Tim' or 'Log - 20221211-donald' for 'Donald'. How can I do that.

in MauiProgram.cs, I added below line, but **here you can add only the folder path, not the file name.**

```
            builder.Logging
            .AddStreamingFileLogger(options =>
            {
                options.MinLevel = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information;
                options.MaxLevel = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Critical;
                options.FolderPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/Android/data/com.companyname.salestracking/files/Logs";
            });
```

Comment: There is a FileNamingParameters class but it does have an option to add an arbitrary string to the name.  The library is open source so you could easily modify it to do what you need

Comment: Is the source code targeted for maui apps too? Could you plz share the link to the source  code? I downloaded MetroLog.Maui Nuget package.

Comment: https://github.com/novotnyllc/MetroLog